# PHP MySQL WHERE clause Column Name error

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL Query:

```
$sSix = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `timers` WHERE `real_id` = {$row['real_id']}";
$rSix = mysql_query($sSix, $conn2);
echo mysql_error(); die;
```

Result:
Unknown column '985_1445542200' in 'where clause'

Column name is `real_id` but in result its showing column '985_1445542200'.

Could you please let me know the probable cause of error.

Comment: Note that PHP's mysql_ API was deprecated several centuries ago,

Comment: I suggest to used the [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of use variable inside a string to avoid sql injection.

Comment: And the mysql_* extension is deprecated and not present anymore in the upcoming release of php 7. It's time to [pick another api](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for connecting to your MySQL server if possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need quotes in your `WHERE` part. Like so:

```
$sSix = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `timers` WHERE `real_id` = '{$row['real_id']}'";
```

Additionally, please consider using the newer `mysqli_` functions or `PDO`, as the old `mysql_` functions will stop working in the future.

Comment: That worked, but I have other queries that worked fine without quotes.

Comment: example: "SELECT `id`, `ch_id`, `time`, `time_to`, `name`, `descr`, `real_id` FROM `epg` WHERE `ch_id` = {$rThreeArray['id']} AND ( ( date(`time`) = '$da' AND date(`time_to`) <= '$next_date' ) OR ( date(`time`) = '$prev_date' AND date(`time_to`) >= '$da' ) ) ORDER BY `time` ASC";

Comment: @KunwarbirS. Please edit your question or post another one instead of writing the queries in the comments. You do not have quotes in the query as well.

Comment: @KunwarbirS.Strings need quotes. Numbers don't. '985_1445542200' is a string

Comment: "I have other queries that worked fine without quotes" - then those queries most likely don't work with string literals but e.g. numbers. `WHERE id=5` is ok, but `WHERE t=mary had a little lamb` is not; in the latter case you have to mark the string literal as such with single quotes for the parser in the MySQL server `WHERE t='mary had a little lamb'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sSix = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `timers` WHERE `real_id` = "'. $row['real_id'].'";
$rSix = mysql_query($sSix, $conn2);
echo mysql_error(); die;
```

Comment: Sorry, this earns you only a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''. $row['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`